# News app loading only first story, no matter which one you click

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a news reader app, but have a problem when loading news.
No matter which one of the offered titles I click, it only displays the first one.
Here is the MainActivity of the project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener, RecyclerViewAdapter.Listener {

    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        setRetrofit();
    }

    public void setRetrofit() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<NewsModel> call = api.getNews();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsModel> call, Response<NewsModel> response) {

                List<Articles> articles = response.body().getArticles();

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                for (int i = 0; i < articles.size(); i++) {
                    mImages.add(articles.get(i).getUrlToImage());
                    mTitle.add(articles.get(i).getTitle());
                }

                initRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsModel> call, Throwable t) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUp.class));
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }

    public void onArticles(List<Articles> articles) {
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.swapData(articles);
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImages, mTitle, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void onItemClickListener (int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DescriptionActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Try to include tags that will help uses to answer you question. For example include the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the adapter after setting the `RecyclerView` `LayoutManager`

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImages, mTitle, this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: Managed to find a problem. Instead of real position for every listed item, integer was set for the page number.

Comment: @Riba good job .. post this as an answer where it might help others in the future